# Entity framework inserts wrong entity into db on savechanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am trying to write a program to scan a directory containing tv show folders, look up some details about the shows using tvrage API and then save the details to a database using entity framework.

My TVShow table pkey is the same value as taken from the tvrage database show id, and I am having issues when duplicate or similar folder names are returning the same Show info. In a situation where I have a directory containing three folders, "Alias", "Alias 1" , "Band of Brothers"  I get the following output from my code

> *   TV SHOWS    *******
>
> Alias....... NO MATCH......ADDING........DONE
>
> Alias 1 ......   NO MATCH.....ADDING....CANT ADD, ID ALREADY EXISTS IN DB
>
> Band of Brothers ......   NO MATCH..ADDING....

Before getting an UpdateException on the context.SaveChanges(); line
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TVShows'.

I can see using SQL profiler that the problem is that my app is trying to perform an insert on the alias show for a second time with duplicate key, but I can't see why. When I step through the code on the second interaction of the foreach loop (second "alias" folder), the code to save the show entity to the database is bypassed.

It is only on the next iteration of the foreach loop when I have created a new TVShow entity for "Band of Brothers" do I 
actually reach the code which adds a Tvshow to context and saves, at which point the app crashes. In visual studio I can see 
at the point of the crash that;

- "show" entity in context.TVShows.AddObject(show) is "Band of Brothers" w/ a unique ID
- context.TVShows only contains one record, the first Alias Entity

But SQL profiler shows that EntityFramework is instead inserting Alias for a second time, and I am stumped by why this is

```
    private void ScanForTVShowFolders( GenreDirectoryInfo drive ) {
        IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> shows = drive.DirInfo.EnumerateDirectories();

        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in shows) {
        //showList contains a list of existing TV show names previously queried out of DB
            if (showList.Contains(d.Name)) {
                System.Console.WriteLine(d.Name + ".....MATCH");

            } else {
                System.Console.Write(d.Name + "......NO MATCH..ADDING....");
                TVShow show = LookUpShowOnline(d.Name, drive.GenreName);

                if (show.Id == -1) {   // id of -1 means online search failed
                    System.Console.Write("..........CANT FIND SHOW" + Environment.NewLine);

                } else if (context.TVShows.Any(a => a.Id == show.Id)) {  //catch duplicate primary key insert
                    System.Console.Write(".......CANT ADD, ID ALREADY EXISTS IN DB" + Environment.NewLine);

                } else {
                    context.TVShows.AddObject(show);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    System.Console.Write("....DONE" + Environment.NewLine);
                }

            }

        }

        private TVShow LookUpShowOnline( string name, string genre ) {

        string xmlPath = String.Format("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/search.php?show='{0}'", name);

        TVShow aShow = new TVShow();
        aShow.Id = -1; // -1 = Can't find

        XmlDocument xmlResp = new XmlDocument();
        try { xmlResp.Load(xmlPath); } catch (WebException e) { System.Console.WriteLine(e); }

        XmlNode root = xmlResp.FirstChild;
        if (root.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration) { root = root.NextSibling; }

        XmlNode tvShowXML;
        //if (showXML["episode"] == null)
        //    return false;

        tvShowXML = root["show"];

        if (tvShowXML != null) {

            aShow.Id = System.Convert.ToInt16(tvShowXML["showid"].InnerText);
            aShow.Name = tvShowXML["name"].InnerText.Trim();
            aShow.StartYear = tvShowXML["started"].InnerText.Trim();
            aShow.Status = tvShowXML["status"].InnerText.Trim();
            aShow.TVGenre = context.TVGenres.Where(b => b.Name.Trim() == genre).Single();
        }

        return aShow;
    }


}
```

*Edit*
Doing some more reading I added context.ObjectStateManager to my debug watchlist and I can see everytime I create a new TVShow entity a new record is added to _addedEntityStore. Actually if I remove  context.TVShows.AddObject(show) the code still updates the database so manually adding to the context seems redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out context.TVShows.AddObject(show) is unnecessary in my case, I was inadvertently adding all created show entities to the context when this query runs

aShow.TVGenre = context.TVGenres.Where(b => b.Name.Trim() == genre).Single();

This is not what I wanted, I just wanted to create the object, then decide whether to add it. Will be pretty easy to fix now I know why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

If your are inserting object by foreach loop > better to keep the Primary Key outside and make it increment!

eg: int newID= Shows.Select(d=>d.Id).Max();

foreach(............)
{

```
show.Id = newID++;  
.  
.  
.  //remaining fields
.
```

context.TVShows.AddObject(show);

}
context.SaveChanges();

it works for me...!!